# Commons email wrong attachment name

Tags: java

I'm using `commons-email-1.2.jar` and I have the issue with the attachment name.

```
private static final String XML_ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME = "Data.xml";
...
email.attach(ds, XML_ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, description, EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
```

The problem is that the attachment name is not `"Data.xml"` but something else related to the media name stored on the database, somehow related to the description + file extension.

Did somebody else face this issue?

UPDATE:
On Windows (Outlook) it's working properly but the problem is on Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on Mac and on some other system, the description is used instead of the attachment name so the solution is to put the name in both fields:

```
email.attach(ds, XML_ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, XML_ATTACHMENT_FILE_NAME, EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the problem here without having logs in place, but you could try the verbose approach:

```java
// Create the attachment
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setPath("foo/foo.jpg");
attachment.setDisposition(EmailAttachment.ATTACHMENT);
attachment.setDescription("Picture");
attachment.setName("Foo");

// Create the email message
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("foo.myserver.com");
email.addTo("foo@bar.com", "Foo Bar");
email.setFrom("example@example.com", "Example");
email.setSubject("Picture");
email.setMsg("Message body example");

// add the attachment
email.attach(attachment);

// send the email
email.send();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that the Mac and some other systems are using the description instead of the attachment name.